# How to replace dll on release build

Tags: msbuild, obfuscation, obfuscar

I have a large solution with a lot of different libraries in and they are used in various solutions. Is it possible to obfuscate and replace the Dll directly before they are copied to projects that reference them, instead of using a separate directory as output?

Comment: https://github.com/lextm/obfuscar/issues/117 impossible.

Comment: At what version did the possibility of doing this break?